# Transforming a string by combining same duplicate characters

Tags: python, strings

I'm solving a programming puzzle that requires to transform an input string by replacing pairs of duplicate consecutive characters with an "incremented" character, recursively, e.g. "abb" -> "ac", "cbb" -> "d". "zz" should be replaced by "a". I'm doing this using a stack:

```
def transform(s):
    stack = []
    for c in s:
        while stack and stack[-1] == c:
            stack.pop()
            c = increment_char(c)
        stack.append(c)
    return ''.join(stack)


def increment_char(char):
    next_char = ord(char) + 1
    if next_char > ord('z'):
        next_char = ord('a')
    return chr(next_char)
```

Is this an optimal algorithm to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you have a link to the original problem description, or ideally the ability to paste it in a quotation?

Comment: What about "aaa"? Does that become "b"?

Comment: @HaiVu No, it should become "ba", since we process the string from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

The only things I readily see that could use improvement:

- Add typehints
- Don't `if`; just use a modulus
- Add some unit tests

### Suggested

```py
from typing import Callable


def transform(s: str) -> str:
    stack = []
    for c in s:
        while stack and stack[-1] == c:
            stack.pop()
            c = increment_char(c)
        stack.append(c)
    return ''.join(stack)


A_OFFSET = ord('a')
WRAP_LEN = ord('z') - A_OFFSET + 1


def increment_char(char: str) -> str:
    index = (ord(char) - A_OFFSET + 1) % WRAP_LEN + A_OFFSET
    return chr(index)


def test(method: Callable[[str], str]) -> None:
    assert method('aa') == 'b'
    assert method('acce') == 'ade'
    assert method('accd') == 'ae'
    assert method('aabcdefg') == 'h'
    assert method('abcdefgg') == 'abcdefh'
    assert method('yyz') == 'a'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test(transform)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a sentinel stack node,

```
stack = [None]
```

guarantees that the stack never goes empty, and the `while` loop simplifies to

```
while stack[-1] == c:
```

which *will* increase the performance, *maybe* significantly. I did not profile.